# Does "שויתי ה׳ לנגדי תמיד" relate to a synagogue?

Tags: synagogue, tehilim-psalms, shulchan-aruch

"שויתי ה׳ לנגדי תמיד" ("I have placed God before me constantly", [Ps. 16:8](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2616.htm#8)) is cited in [*Rama* (*OC* 1:1)](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayyim.1.1) as support for what he writes there: that one should be aware that he's always before God, who can see all his actions, including when he's alone at home or in bed.

Many synagogues have this verse quoted on their walls. I've don't recall ever seeing it, however, in any other religious-run establishment, such as a home, or a retail shop, or a classroom, or an office, or….

Is there a source that specifically connects the verse, especially a *Rama*esque interpretation thereof,  to synagogue-type activities (Torah study and/or prayer, I guess)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider [Bavli Sanhedrin 22a](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=3653):

> אמר רב חנה בר ביזנא אמר רבי שמעון חסידא: המתפלל צריך שיראה עצמו כאילו שכינה כנגדו, שנאמר שויתי ה' לנגדי תמיד.‏
>   Rav Chana son of Bizna said in the name of Rabbi Shimon Chasida: One who prays must see himself as if the Shechina were opposite him, as [it says](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2616.htm#8), "I have set the LORD always before me."

Comment: (I make no claim about the origin of any particular custom. You asked for a source making such a connection.)

Comment: And echoed in Shulchan Aruch 98:1 הַמִּתְפַּלֵּל צָרִיךְ שֶׁיְּכַוֵּן בְּלִבּוֹ פֵּרוּשׁ הַמִּלּוֹת שֶׁמּוֹצִיא בִּשְׂפָתָיו; וְיַחֲשֹׁב כְּאִלּוּ שְׁכִינָה כְּנֶגְדּוֹ